# Lightboxed images get distorted when double-tapping or pinch-zooming

Tags: css, pinchzoom, photoswipe, distortion

I'm using Photoswipe Masonry Gallery plugin (WP), but when the images are double-tapped or pinch-zoomed, they get distorted. 
[image: Pls see this for easy reference]

Any idea what is causing this? It's not a plugin issue, as it works perfectly when switched to Twenty Fifteen theme. FYI, I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`. Anything suspicious in the below CSS I'm using?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    /* basics */

    #content,
    #sidebar,
    .endbar_left,
    .endbar_right {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content {
        margin-left: 0%;
        padding-left: 0%;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    html,
    body {
        width: auto !important;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
    img {
        border: none;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    #header {
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
    /* posts */

    .inside2 {
        padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    }
    .post {
        padding-right: 3px;
    }
    .pics_article {
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help. FYI, I'm not a web developer. Someone with okay html/css knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @pierre-lebon for the edit. Sorry, I'm very new here...

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution by myself! It was `!important;` in my `img` properties (not in the above-posted @media query, but in the main part of CSS) causing this distortion. Removing `!important;` from the below has resolved the issue.

```
img {
    border: none;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;}
```